# How do I examine controller data such as for the Sustain Pedal in Reaper?

Tags: midi, reaper

I have Reaper 4.261 and am trying to view the controller data (specifically for the sustain pedal). I've tried reading the manual, but it didn't help much.

How do I view the controller data in Reaper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Reaper, you can view controller data in the MIDI editor.

To open the editor, right click on the MIDI track you wish to view and select Built-in MIDI editor->Open in editor.

[image]

In the MIDI editor there is a drop down list in the lower left corner.  Select 64 Hold Pedal (on/off).  You should see the sustain pedal controller data in the bottom portion of the window.

Comment: You're my hero. Thanks. *upvotes and accepts*